# fwrite() can display number_format() in PHP

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm doing function to export CSV file in PHP. but when i do an export, i need to add information about total in number_format().. but display is wrong.

Here is my code

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

$file = fopen("report.csv", "w");  

fwrite($file, "Generate Report \r\n"); 
fwrite($file, "Total Sales, ".number_format($total)."\r\n");
fwrite($file, " "."\r\n");
```

the result is this

[image]

and that is wrong.

How do i can display the correct format number like "5,485" or maybe "5,485.00" in 1 cell on CSV file?

please help

Comment: fwrite($file, "Total Sales, \"".number_format($total)."\"\r\n");

Comment: The fwrite() writes to an open file.
The function will stop at the end of the file (EOF) or when it reaches the specified length, whichever comes first.

Comment: thankyou @user10099 it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fwrite(resource $handle, string $string, int $length = ?): 

fwrite($file, "Total Sales, \"".number_format($total)."\"\r\n");
```

`int fwrite()` writes the contents of string to the file stream pointed to by handle.

Return Values `fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written, or false on error.

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. How does this help to use proper formatting within that file?

Comment: @ferdinand  it's helpful?